# Previous pdf in response

Tags: java, gwt, wkhtmltopdf, gxt

I have servlet, which create html-file and then convert it to pdf-file:

```
private void ConvertHTMLtoPDF(String sConvertationProgramm, String sHTML, String sPDF)
{        
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(sConvertationProgramm, sHTML, sPDF);
        Process process = pb.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Everything work perfect, but then I open this ***new*** (as I think) generated pdf-file from this code:

```
ConvertHTMLtoPDF("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe",
                "PDFtemplate/requiredPDF.html",
                "PDFtemplate/Report.pdf");
response.sendRedirect("PDFtemplate/Report.pdf");
```

- that gave me previous pdf-file, which was created before.
Furthermore I've tried to open it from Windows explorer, and it's also showed me previous file every first opens.

---

Does anybody have any suggestion what's happen and how to solve this problem?

Any input would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing `response.sendRedirect("PDFtemplate/Report.pdf")` after starting some process. You should wait finish of that process and only after finishing make other actions.

Use `process.waitFor();`

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are replacing your current file with the new one, I doubt you are writing your new file into this location.

Comment: I demand so, cause every time I want to create pdf-file, that code is calling. May be I need  some **refresh** function. Nevertheless, according to your words, how it's work on the second call? As I say before it's work perfect from the second time.

Comment: That may be happening because you are trying to access it before it is getting written, add some delay and check

Comment: Look like this is work, but how to do it without delay, after writing is completed?

Comment: Thread.currentThread().sleep(yourTimeInMilliseconds); , e.g:- Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); or static method Thread.sleep(1000); that by default would put current thread to sleep for specified time.

Comment: Yep, I've done it and it's work, thank you. But issue I want was showed bellow.